# Sum of normal random variables

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, normally distributed random variables with mean zero and variances $\sigma_x^2$ and $\sigma_y^2$ respectively. I am trying to evaluate
$$ \mathbb{P}(X + Y > 0 | X > 0), $$
Some questions:

- Is this possible to obtain closed form expressions for this probability (I suspect not)?
- Can one prove formally how this probability depends on the variances. For example, how can I prove that $\mathbb{P}(X + Y > 0 | X > 0)$ rises when $\sigma_y^2$ falls (if that is true)?

Many thanks in advance for any ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\Phi$ denote the $N(0,\,1)$ CDF. At fixed $x\in\Bbb R$, $P(x+Y>0)=\Phi(x/\sigma_y)$, so$$P(X+Y>0|X>0)=2\int_0^\infty\frac{\Phi(x/\sigma_y)}{\sigma_x\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma_x^2}dx$$(the factor of $2$ comes from dividing out $\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sigma_x\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma_x^2}dx=\frac12$). With $z:=x/\sigma_x$, we see there's really only one degree of freedom: let $\kappa:=\sigma_x/\sigma_y$ so$$P(X+Y>0|X>0)=2\int_0^\infty\frac{\Phi(\kappa z)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\frac{-z^2}{2}dz.$$This function of $\kappa$ is $\frac12$ when $\kappa=0$ and has $\kappa$-derivative$$\int_0^\infty\frac{z}{\pi}\exp\frac{-(\kappa^2+1)z^2}{2}dz=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{\kappa^2+1},$$so$$P(X+Y>0|X>0)=\frac12+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\kappa.$$Unsurprisingly, this $\to1^-$ as $\kappa\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer! Could you briefly explain how you get from
$$ 2\int_0^\infty\frac{\Phi(\kappa z)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\frac{-z^2}{2}dz $$
to
$$\frac12+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\kappa$$?

Comment: @afreelunch It's a function of $\kappa$, which we can [differentiate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) as in my answer, using$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\kappa}\Phi(\kappa z)=z\Phi'(\kappa z)=\frac{z}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\frac{-\kappa^2z^2}{2}.$$But at $\kappa=0$, $\Phi=\frac12$ for all $z$, so the original expression becomes$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\frac{-z^2}{2}dz=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\frac{-z^2}{2}dz=\frac12.$$